# Is there a better way to set up the database for tests?

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit

I have the following test class:

```
class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $em;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->em = getEntityManager(true);
        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->em);

        $mdFactory = $this->em->getMetadataFactory();
        $tool->dropSchema($mdFactory->getallMetadata());
        $tool->createSchema($mdFactory->getallMetadata());
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->em);

        $mdFactory = $this->em->getMetadataFactory();
        $tool->dropSchema($mdFactory->getallMetadata());
        parent::tearDown();
    }
    ...
}
```

The `setUp` function sets up the test database with the schema of the production, then tears it down after every test. Right now my out put is this:

```
Configuration read from /var/www/html/Grab-Project/phpunit.xml

...

Time: 8.03 seconds, Memory: 20.00Mb

OK (3 tests, 3 assertions)
```

8 seconds isnt too bad, but I plan to add a crap load more tests to this file and its only gonna grow in time.

Is there a way to set up the schema, then check if the schema exists on the next go around? if so do nothing? and then on tear down say, delete all data from the database but leave the schema alone?

Comment: You can use the static method setUpBeforeClass to create the schema once.  https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html . Might want to read the chapter on database testing for further hints.  https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html.  You did not say which database is being used but sqlite is probably the fastest.  You might also ask yourself why you need so many functional tests.  Perhaps mocking could be used.